# MS Access: error using aggregate function MAX

Tags: jquery, sql, ms-access, max

I am having trouble making an aggregate function work. MS Access compalins about how I'm using the aggregate function:

```
   SELECT Max([RENEW_DATE]) AS Expr1
    FROM RENEW_TRANSACTIONS INNER JOIN CIRC_TRANSACTIONS ON  
     RENEW_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID = 
     CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
      WHERE (("circ_transaction_id"=[circ_transactions].
       [circ_transaction_id]))
     order by  CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

The error I get is "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID' as part of an aggregate funciton"
I have two tables, circ_transactions and renew_transactions. The first represents a patron checking out a book.  The second represents the renewals the patron got on the book. So circ to renew is 1-N.

I need all the circ items and, if it exists, the renew_date. However, if there are multiple renew dates, I need the most recent. I've tried to go at this several different ways, some written by me and some written )(mostlY) by Access 2007. I tried a select as a field.  Didn't work.  I tried the above.  Doesn't work. In a couple of versions, even though Access generated 
RENEW_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
it had trouble with that same identifier copied to a different query. (It gave the dialog box that expects a value, which I've learned means I typed something incorrectly, but I could not find that here.)
So either as a standalone query, or as part of the larger query that it relates to with a long set of inner joins, how can I get the max(renew date)? I'd actually like to do this:

```
select RENEW_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID, circ_transactions.item_id, circ_transactions.circ_transaction_id, MAX(renew_date)
```

but I assume this won't work either.

What do I need to do to get this to work? I'd prefer to make the max value code by itself a query as a field in a larger query, but I'll take any approach that works.  Right now my larger query gets about 1690 circ ttransaction ids, but a query for renew date without the MAX gets me 1785, alomst one hundred extra rows. I need to get this data and send it to our vendor today. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You Probably also want to group it by the CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID, so you can see the date for each item.

```
SELECT CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID, Max([RENEW_DATE]) AS Expr1
FROM RENEW_TRANSACTIONS INNER JOIN CIRC_TRANSACTIONS ON  
RENEW_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID = 
CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
GROUP BY CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
ORDER BY CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that on this version, I get an error in the where clause (apparently). "where" is highlighted and Access says, "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID' WHERE (("circ_transaction_id"=[circ_transactions].
[circ_transaction_id]))

Comment: I tried removing all the extra [] and quote marks, but that didn't help. I also tried moving the group by after the where clause as iI haenormally seen a gorup by after the where clause. Makes no difference.

Comment: @DocDuncan Sorry, the where clause is completely unneccessary unless you want to filter the results to a specific transaction id.  I edited to remove this.

Comment: I have a follow-on question. It looks like I should put that in a new thread. However, your code, tweaked a bit for exactly what I want, worked well:

Comment: SELECT CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID, Max([RENEW_DATE]) AS 

Expr1
FROM CIRC_TRANSACTIONS LEFT JOIN RENEW_TRANSACTIONS ON  
CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID = 
RENEW_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
GROUP BY CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID
ORDER BY CIRC_TRANSACTIONS.CIRC_TRANSACTION_ID;